# Verilog: Design counter using adder

Tags: verilog

The following is one simple 4 bit up counter verilog code I made using a 4 bit adder verilog code ( a working file , tested). I happens that when I include the adder instantiation the clock stops working and hence entire code stops working. Any suggestions of what possibly went wrong????

```
module four_bit_counter(
output reg [3:0] a
);
 reg clock ;
 reg [3:0] temp;
 initial
 begin
    a = 4'b0000;
    clock =0 ;
    temp = 4'b0000;   // Remove this
 end

 four_bit_adder add(.a(temp), .b(4'b0001), .s(a));   //  four_bit_adder add(.a(a), .b(4'b0001), .s(temp));

 always  begin 
    #10 clock = ~clock;
 end

 always @(posedge clock) 
    begin 
        assign temp = a;  // a<=temp;
    end

endmodule
```

// 4 bit adder code:

module four_bit_adder(

```
 input  [3:0] a, 
 input  [3:0] b,
output reg [3:0] s  // Type wire
); 
 wire [3:0] sum;   
 wire [3:0] c ; 
    full_adder f1( .a(a[0]) , .b(b[0]), .cin(1'b0), .s(sum[0]), .c(c[0]) );
    full_adder f2( .a(a[1]) , .b(b[1]), .cin(c[0]), .s(sum[1]), .c(c[1]) );
    full_adder f3( .a(a[2]) , .b(b[2]), .cin(c[1]), .s(sum[2]), .c(c[2]) ); 
    full_adder f4( .a(a[3]) , .b(b[3]), .cin(c[2]), .s(sum[3]), .c(c[3]) );

    always begin 
        assign s = sum;
    end
```

endmodule

Comment: please tell me a way to add code in a proper way...

Comment: WHY can't we connect s to a ???

Comment: I was using xiling tool... There was this warning                Target <temp> of concurrent assignment or output port connection should be a net type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the bug. Was thinking of the verilog code as a normal C code with variables. Could resolve the problem when thought of it at hardware level. I have commented the changes which needed to be done to make it work.